# MySQL REGEX a partial word in a word

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to match a word against other words with REGEX in MySQL but I can't get it right.

For example a search for the word `foo` should match the following (case insensitive):

```
foobar
barfoo
foofoo
football
foo-bar
foo_bar
```

And not match spaces between them like:

```
foo bar
```

I searched the web and found some REGEX but they don't match all the above options.

This is my current pattern:

```
REGEX '[[:<:]]'.$word.'(![:space:])[[:>:]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you'll allow any non-whitespace characters before or after `foo`.

Then you can use

```
'^[^[:space:]]*'.$word.'[^[:space:]]*$'
```

Translated to PCRE regex where `\S` means a non-space character and `\b` means a word boundary:

```
^\S*foo\S*$
```

So this matches words that contain `foo` but don't contain any whitespace.

Comment: Well this works almost, it does not match the full word 'foo' only if its in a word like foobar. the exact word foo does not get matched

Comment: Your examples did not show that you want to match `foo` alone, and your counterexample has a whole word `foo` in `foo bar` that should *not* be matched...but that's possible. Will edit if you could tell me whether the first or the second regex is the one that fits your needs better.

Comment: Yes my bad! sorry

The second fits me best!

Comment: How would one use this approach to pattern match 'C# Developer, Developed C++, JavaScript Development' to select the entire WORD variations of "Develop*"? I can't get it to work with the latest ICU approach, and the above example doesn't pattern match the entire word properly.